# Unable to connect to MySQL database using Python: OperationalError

Tags: python, mysql

I am working on a Python project that involves connecting to a MySQL database.
I'm using the mysql-connector library for database connectivity.
Issue:

I'm encountering an OperationalError when trying to establish a connection to the MySQL database.
The error message is:

> OperationalError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (10061)"

Comment: Are you sure you started the database server?

Comment: can you connect with console tool `mysql`? Or you can use other tools - like [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/), [HeidiSQL](https://www.heidisql.com/). Does the database run on your local computer?

Comment: [Edit] your question and post your code that connects to the database.